# What are the best online tools to easily make json rpc calls?

Tags: contract-invocation, json-rpc, eth-call

What are the best tools to make any of the [Ethereum json rpc](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/) method requests online in addition to easily interacting with smart contracts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the following 3 tools to be very useful for different use cases.

1. https://ethereum.github.io/execution-apis/api-documentation/
2. https://justsmartcontracts.dev/#/
3. https://neptunemutual.com/web3-tools/solidity-abi-encoder-online/
4. https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum

The first is good overall for making specific json rpc method calls(e.g. `eth_getTransactionByHash`, etc), however requires manually entering the params to a query which isn't too much of an issue as it specifies the schema for reference.

The second and third are very good at doing one thing i.e. interacting with smart contracts via `eth_call`. You simply load the contract's abi, specify the json rpc URL and the contract address and it makes all the no parameter function calls automatically and shows all other contract calls that can be made and displays the required number of parameter inputs.

The QuickNode docs is helpful if you want to simply copy a curl URL for one of the json rpc methods quickly.

Answer (score 1):

### ETH JSON RPC

- Not all RPC Endpoints will support all methods.

#### RPC by UI

We use this https://web3-rpc-debug.vercel.app -- is a fork of quicknodes tool (mentioned by Sahil Sen) but with updated code samples and better JSON RPC handling.

#### RPC by API

Here is Besu's JSON RPC Methods in a Postman Collection

[image: Run in Postman]

##### Ref. RPC docs

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/14127676/2s8YzXwLiD

#### Uncensored RPC Endpoint

I founded an endpoint called https://securerpc.com - zero content filters so you can be sure it's not us making issues with your requests.

Answer (score 0):

An additional tool is EtherFlow https://etherflow.quiknode.io/ to make RPC calls in web3.js or ethers.js. You can also get code samples.